# What's different between \Phalcon\Mvc\User\Component and Phalcon\Mvc\User\Plugin

Tags: phalcon

There are \Phalcon\Mvc\User\Component and Phalcon\Mvc\User\Plugin in Phalcon. In the sample invo, Phalcon\Mvc\User\Plugin is used for EventsManager [in here](https://github.com/phalcon/invo/blob/master/app/plugins/Security.php#L6). In mvc sample, Phalcon\Mvc\User\Component is used [in here](https://github.com/phalcon/mvc/blob/master/multiple/apps/library/Acl.php#L6). I wonder what is the difference between these two classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, both classes are currently the same. The more we extend the framework, specific functionality may be added to aid building mvc plugins and user components